# Set a location to the Map in a business info page

Tags: ios, dictionary, location

I'm designing an app for a restaurant (and also, mostly to practice with iOS dev).

For this restaurant info page (address, phone #, etc)  I added a smaller Map on the bottom page to display the place where the restaurant is but:

- how can I make this small map to display the restaurant location (I know the coordinates) and
- how to code that if the user click on the map, it switches to Apple Map app with the same coordinates.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `MKMapViewDelegate` in your `viewcontroller.h` file and use the ma delegate's methods to handle the map.

Try with the code below to add the pin of the restaurant and center the map on it.

```
MKAnnotationView *point = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:_station reuseIdentifier:@"restaurant"];

[map addAnnotation:point.annotation];

MKCoordinateRegion region;
MKCoordinateSpan span;
span.latitudeDelta = 0.002;
span.longitudeDelta = 0.002;
region.span = span;
region.center = location.coordinate;
[map setRegion:region animated:YES];
```

After that, implement the `didSelectAnnotationView` method to recognize the pin pressed. In it you can open the Apple Map with on the restaurant's coordinates:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {

    NSString *title = @"title";
    float latitude = ...;
    float longitude = ...;
    int zoom = 13;
    NSString *stringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.apple.com?q=%@@%1.6f,%1.6f&z=%d", title, latitude, longitude, zoom];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
```

EDIT:

I'm working to an application similar to your, but in my case is about station.
`MDStationController` is the controller of the view that contains the map on the top (like yours). `MDStation` is the station.

```
// MDStationController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MDStation.h"
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MDStationController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, retain) MDStation* station;

@end

// MDStationController.m 

@implementation MDStationController
@synthesize station=_station;

[...]

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.title = _station.name;
    stationView.map.delegate = self;
    [self addAndcenterMapOnLocation:_station.location]; 
}

- (void) addAndcenterMapOnLocation:(CLLocation*)location {

    MKAnnotationView *point = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:_station reuseIdentifier:@"station"];

    [stationView.map addAnnotation:point.annotation];

    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta = 0.002;
    span.longitudeDelta = 0.002;
    region.span = span;
    region.center = location.coordinate;
    [stationView.map setRegion:region animated:YES];
}

-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {

    static NSString *defaultID = @"station";
    MKAnnotationView *pinView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultID];
    pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bike_gray"];
    return pinView;
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {

    NSString *title = _station.name;
    float latitude = _station.location.latitude;
    float longitude = _station.location.longitude;
    int zoom = 13;
    NSString *stringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.apple.com?q=%@@%1.6f,%1.6f&z=%d", title, latitude, longitude, zoom];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
```

Comment: ok, i have 10 compiler errors.  I guess I have something wrong.  I also haven't anything else on the project too so, thats maybe why.
You said to type it in the ViewController.h file but I created a ContactVC.h&m files for the Contact view, is that correct (what I learned in books)    thanks

Comment: Do you still have problems?

Comment: Hello again!  thanks for this detailed post.  Unfortunately, I tried to adapt it to my needs and Xcode's gives me a couple of (!).   All about those .name, .location, _restaurantView.map, etc that it doesn't know...  I guess I didn't implement or initialized them the right way....

Comment: I'm new to Objective-C/iOS.... starting by playing around with Maps is maybe too difficult for someone of my level.    I was trying to follow a tutorial from a book but I see that I can't handle it on my own...

Comment: I suggest you www.raywenderlich.com. I used it very often.
http://www.raywenderlich.com/21365/introduction-to-mapkit-in-ios-6-tutorial

Comment: Oh!  thanks for that!  I was aware of this website but not that they have all this content!